# Endpoints for Two factor authentication using Django REST

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, two-factor-authentication

I am creating an api for authenticating the user with a two factor auth upon login.

The Following view is redirected to after the login is successful.

```
class TOTPView(APIView):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.verified = False
        self.last_verified_counter = -1
        self.totp = self.generate_totp()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.debug(self.totp)

        return Response({'success': True},
                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def post(self, request):
        token = int(request.data.get('totp_token'))

        # check if the current counter value is higher than the value of
        # last verified counter and check if entered token is correct by
        # calling totp.verify_token()
        if ((self.totp.t() > self.last_verified_counter) and
                (self.totp.verify(token))):
            # if the condition is true, set the last verified counter value
            # to current counter value, and return True
            self.last_verified_counter = self.totp.t()
            self.verified = True

            return Response({'success': True},
                            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        else:
            # if the token entered was invalid or if the counter value
            # was less than last verified counter, then return False
            self.verified = False

            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def generate_totp(self):
        key = random_hex(20)
        totp = TOTP(key)

        totp.time = time.time()

        return totp
```

Here, when the user posts the OTP code/token, the POST method calls `self.totp` and that overwrites its value by calling `self.generate_totp()` again. That never validates the TOTP.
Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are generating a new key for your TOTP each time. Instead, you should save the key against the user that is logging in so that you always validate against the same key. I presume you're sharing a key to the user somehow (by QR code?) so that they can add it to an authenticator application and generate tokens.

One other thing, I notice you are casting the token to an integer. Tokens should be strings as they may include leading zeros that you would lose by casting to integer.